# Collecting time in datagridview

Tags: c#

Before I had a double format in the table so I could collate the column and get the result as "Saldo" at the end of the table, how can I do it with DATETIME?

[image]

```
if (e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
{
    e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    switch (e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            //e.Value = "Saldo";
            // e.Value = benutzer;
        break;
        case 1:
            double sum = 0.0d;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex; i++)
            {
                var value = this.dataGridView1[1, i].Value;
                if (value is double)
                {
                    sum += ((double)value);
                }
            }
            e.Value = "Saldo: " + Math.Round(sum, 1);
        break;
        case 2:
            e.Value = benutzer;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for help

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, result should be: 9:00 + 8:30 = 17:30 ?

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code? Is `value is double` evaluated to true or false?

Comment: is the datatype of the `Stunden` column `DateTime` ? Can you change it to `TimeSpan` ? Then it would work as if you would have `double`

Comment: I guess you want to get the difference between 01.03.2017 to 13.12.2017?

TimeSpan duration = dateTimeb - dateTimea; to get this

Comment: To sum use : `var totalSum = new TimeSpan(YourData.Sum(y => y.TheField.Ticks));`

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on `DateTime` values like that. Look at using `TimeSpan` values instead.

Comment: Column "Stunden" is a TimeSpan type, I only need to assemble these hours 09:00:00 + 08: 30: 00 = 17: 30: 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apprently, the `value` is not a double, so the sum is never changed.
Change the code

```
if (value is double)
{
    sum += ((double)value);
}
```

to

```
if (value is TimeSpan)
{
    sum += ((TimeSpan)value).TotalHours;
}
```

The `TotalHours` property returns the hours as a fractional value of type double, e.g. `8.5`. Also see the [Documentation of the TotalHours property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you rather desire an Output like 17:30:00 you should sum the values as TimeSpan like so:

```
        case 1:
            TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.FromHours(0.0);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex; i++)
            {
                var value = this.dataGridView1[1, i].Value;
                if (value is TimeSpan)
                {
                    sum += ((TimeSpan)value);
                }
            }
            e.Value = "Saldo: " + sum;
        break;
```

Comment: Addting time span like this will cut the minute , second, etc?

Comment: @DragandDrop No, the property TotalHours returns the hours as double. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx